# I'm currently trying to make a registration page using Prepared Statements, fails on ->prepare

Tags: php, web

I'm currently trying to make a registration page using Prepared Statements, fails on ->prepare

I keep ending up at the else statement `Something Went Wrong`, I just don't know what's wrong, also for some reason since going from mysqli_query to these prepared statements it seems like no errors are being echo'd ( normally I'd get a white page with some mysql error on it but nothing now, is that a `php.ini` problem? And could anybody tell me just how 'secure' my code is from injections and what not? Thanks.

Update 1:

Added the closing bracket on the ->prepare now I'm getting this error

`[Thu Feb 28 21:40:00 2013] [error] [client 68.150.102.145] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot pass parameter 6 by reference in /var/www/busapp/register.php on line 25`

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
    $firstname = $_POST['inputFirstName'];
    $lastname = $_POST['inputLastName'];
    $originalpassword = SHA1($_POST['inputOriginalPassword']);
    $confirmpassword = SHA1($_POST['inputConfirmPassword']);
    $createdip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    require_once('connectdb.php');

    /* Connect to the database */

    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_BASE);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Users (Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password, Admin, Activated, CreatedIP, Datecreated)
                                 values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?")) {
        /* Bind our params */

        $stmt->bind_param('ssssiiss', $firstname, $lastname, $email, $originalpassword, 0, 0, $createdip, NOW());

        /* Execute statement */

            $stmt -> execute();
            $alert = '<p class="alert-success">Account created, check your email for an activation link.</p>';

            $mysqli -> close();
            $stmt -> close();
    } else {
            $alert = '<p class="alert-error"> Something went wrong </p>';
            $mysqli -> close();
    }
}
require_once('navbar.php');
?>
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 35px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Register</h2>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email Address" name="inputEmail">
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="First Name" name="inputFirstName">
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Last Name" name="inputLastName">
    <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" name="inputOriginalPassword">
    <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="inputConfirmPassword">
    <?php echo $alert; ?>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Register</button>
</form>
</div>


<?php require_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: what is this for require_once('connectdb.php'); ????

Comment: Just my db username password and what not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Users (Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password, Admin, Activated, CreatedIP, Datecreated)
                                 values(?, ?, ?, ?, 0, 0, ?, NOW())")) {
    /* Bind our params */
    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $firstname, $lastname, $email, $originalpassword, $createdip);
```

//rest of your code

Besides the left out parenthesis, you don't need to bind `NOW()` and two const values `0`.

Comment: How unsafe is it to use const values instead of ? and then declaring what they are, and why don't I need to bind NOW(), sorry, making the switch to Prepared Statements and it seems completely different than my old methods :)

Comment: Since you don't get those values from outside it's safe to use them as part of your SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for being direct and to the point, before switching to prepared I mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(asdasdasd)) is that still necessary with this method? Or is my code safe?

Comment: **[Escaping and SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):
Bound variables will be escaped automatically by the server.** The server inserts their escaped values at the appropriate places into the statement template before execution.

Comment: In terms of escaping yes, but it's always a good idea to sanitize and validate user input as early in the process as possible.

Comment: In your case it might be checks that all required fields are passed, they are not empty, check for max lengths, strip tags etc.

Answer (score 0):

use below code, your query is wrong.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Users (Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password, Admin, Activated, CreatedIP, Datecreated)
                             values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
                                                          ^ // you forgot ) here
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error `[Thu Feb 28 21:40:00 2013] [error] [client ] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot pass parameter 6 by reference in /var/www/busapp/register.php on line 25`

Comment: @GeT_Lurk3D which is line 25?

Comment: Oh sorry, the ->prepare, basically the 6th ? which is equal to Activated 0